# Does resolution width and height value swap on device rotation?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, user-interface, screen-resolution

I was wondering if these two change their value when the device is rotated.

```
float currentResolutionX = Screen.currentResolution.width;
float currentResolutionY = Screen.currentResolution.height;

Debug.Log(currentResolutionX + "x" + currentResolutionY) // 1080x1920

// now let's rotate the device to landscape

Debug.Log(currentResolutionX + "x" + currentResolutionY) // ??? 1920x1080 ???
```

I am making different UI for portrait and landscape modes. So to calculate correctly the size of UI elements I need to know if I have to use swapped values.
For e.g., say a device has 1080x1920 resolution. When it's rotated does that change to 1920x1080 internally? What I mean is will `Screen.currentResolution.width` change to 1920 or will it remain 1080? I am not sure how os handles rotation.

Comment: Do the comments reflect what you tested?

Comment: The first comment, yes, the second one is not tested, and I am trying to learn if it will debug the values like that. Unfortunately, I can't test it, so I gotta rely on your experience.

Comment: Why didn't you test in Unity Editor? You can test it just by swapping resouliton. You can check phone orientation by this property [Screen.orientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html)

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I debugged using the property that you mentioned and seems like in both cases initial resolution doesn't change. Screen.currentResolution width and height remain unswapped.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged using @SeLeCtRa 's advice. Turns out  `Screen.currentResolution`  width and height remain unswapped.